# How to join all threads before deleting the ThreadPool

Tags: multithreading, c++11, mutex

I am using a MultiThreading class which creates the required number of threads in its own threadpool and deletes itself after use.

```
std::thread *m_pool;      //number of threads according to available cores
std::mutex m_locker;
std::condition_variable m_condition;
std::atomic<bool> m_exit;
int m_processors    

m_pool = new std::thread[m_processors + 1]

void func()
{
   //code
}

for (int i = 0; i < m_processors; i++)
{
    m_pool[i] = std::thread(func);
}

void reset(void)
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_locker);
        m_exit = true;
    }
    m_condition.notify_all();

    for(int i = 0; i <= m_processors; i++)
        m_pool[i].join();
    delete[] m_pool;
}
```

After running through all tasks, the for-loop is supposed to join all running threads before `delete[]` is being executed. 
But there seems to be one last thread still running, while the `m_pool` does not exist anymore.
This leads to the problem, that I can't close my program anymore.
Is there any way to check if all threads are joined or wait for all threads to be joined before deleting the threadpool?

Comment: Watch out for your loop conditions  `i < m_processors` ...  `i <= m_processors`

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo bug I think.

Your loop that has the condition `i <= m_processors` is a *bug* and will actually process one extra entry past the end of the array.  This is an off-by-one bug. Suppose m_processors is 2.  You'll have an array that contains 2 elements with indices [0] and [1].  Yet, you'll be reading past the end of the array, attempting to join with the item at index [2].  `m_pool[2]` is undefined memory and you're likely going to either crash or block forever there.

You likely intended `i < m_processors`.

Answer (score 0):

The real source of the problem is addressed by Wick's answer. I will extend it with some tips that also solve your problem while improving other aspects of your code.

If you use C++11 for `std::thread`, then you shouldn't create your thread handles using `operator new[]`. There are better ways of doing that with other C++ constructs, which will make everything simpler **and exception safe** (you don't leak memory if an unexpected exception is thrown).

- Store your thread objects in a `std::vector`. It will manage the memory allocation and deallocation for you (no more `new` and `delete`). You can use other more flexible containers such as `std::list` if you insert/delete threads dynamically.
- Fill the vector in place with `std::generate` or similar

---

```
std::vector<std::thread> m_pool;
m_pool.reserve(n_processors);

// Fill the vector
std::generate_n( std::back_inserter(m_pool), m_processors, 
                 [](){ return std::thread(func); } );
```

- Join all the elements using range-for loop and delete handles using container's functions.

---

```
for( std::thread& t: m_pool ) {
  t.join();
}
m_pool.clear();
```